# Rails FactoryGirl pass empty string after create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

I have a ruby app that I'm using rspec and factorygirl with, and I'm having trouble building a factory. Let me explain with an example:

I've got two factories which are creating `registrant.user_demographic` like below:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :registrant do
    first_name { "Johnny #{Faker::Name.initials}" }
    (...)

    after(:build) do |registrant|
      registrant.user_demographic ||= build(:user_demographic, user: registrant)
    end
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user_demographic do
    user { create(:registrant) }
    phone "1234567890"
    (...)
  end
end
```

Now I want to have registrant without phone number sth like: `registrant.user_demographic.phone == ''`. I've tried with transient defined in `user_demographic` but it won't work:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :registrant do
    first_name { "Johnny #{Faker::Name.initials}" }
    (...)

    after(:build) do |registrant|
      registrant.user_demographic ||= build(:user_demographic, user: registrant)
    end

    trait :without_phone do
      after(:build) do |registrant|
        registrant.user_demographic ||= build(:user_demographic, user: registrant, phone_present: false)
      end
    end
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user_demographic do
    (...)

    transient do
      phone_present { true }
    end

    phone { '1234567890' if phone_present }
  end
end
```

Comment: Side note: I suggest using `FactoryBot` instead of `FactoryGirl`. `FactoryBot` is the direct successor of `FactoryGirl`. `FactoryGirl` was abandoned more than 4 years ago and will not get any security or maintenance updates anymore.

Comment: @spickermann I know that but my app is 6y old and well... I only make the necessary changes.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `registrant.user_demographic.phone == ''` ?

Comment: @R.Sierra yes, it is possible to declare sth like `registrant.user_demographic.phone = ''` directly in the test but I want to have it available quickly and in many places so I would like to use a tool that has been created for this purpose - FactoryGirl.

Comment: @mr_muscle Sorry for the misunderstanding, I was just pointing out that you placed `registrant.user_demographic == ''` in the example instead of `registrant.user_demographic.phone == ''`

Comment: I would suggest passing the value to the transient attribute without a block like: `phone_present true` insead of `phone_present { true}`